# Gparted: Cannot expand the partition

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I want to extend my partition. I have shrunk the partition in Windows and have my unallocated space. But, when I want to extend my Ubuntu partition by using Gparted, I cannot expand the partition because Gparted doesn't read any free space surrounding my main partition. I hope this image may give clearer picture of what I was saying:
[image]

As you see in the image, the unallocated space is in the front of sda5, which I want to extend. But, Gparted doesn't detect any free space preceding to sda5. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to expand the extended partition (the light blue one, /dev/sda3 in your case) first. Then you will be able to expand /dev/sda5.

Comment: In my live USB, the sda3 is locked, I think, I have to unmount it. So, when I'm done with resizing the sda5, should I do another thing? Or I just restart the computer?

Comment: It should be enough.